# Al intentar transformar líneas de un fichero a un diccionario, solo aparece como diccionario la última línea del fichero

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que me pide crear un programa que lea un fichero de texto y transforme cada línea del mismo en un diccionario, entre otras cosas.
El problema es que una vez que ejecuto el código, solo me aparece como diccionario la última línea del fichero.

Ejercicio:

> El fichero de texto se denominará personas.txt y tendrá el siguiente contenido en texto plano (créalo previamente):

```
1;Carlos;Pérez;05/01/1989
2;Manuel;Heredia;26/12/1973
3;Rosa;Campos;12/06/1961
4;David;García;25/07/2006
```

> Los campos del diccionario serán por orden: `id`, `nombre`, `apellido` y `nacimiento`.

```
#Vamos a transformar cada linea del fichero en un diccionario:
d = {}     
with open("personas.txt") as fichero:
   for linea in fichero:
      (val1,val2,val3,val4) = linea.split(";")
      d["id"] = val1                           
      d["nombre"] = val2
      d["apellido"] = val3
      d["nacimiento"] = val4
      
print(d)
```

La salida por pantalla del código es la siguiente:

```
{'id': '4', 'nombre': 'David', 'apellido': 'García', 'nacimiento': '25/07/2006'}
```

Comment: Es por que en un diccionario las claseves son únicas, lo que haces es sobrescribir cada clave en cada interacción, por ende te quedas con la última. Lo que puedes hacer es tener una lista y en esa lista guardar cada diccionario.

Comment: En el `for` cada iteración sobreescribe el mismo diccionario, no sé si necesites una lista de diccionarios o un diccionario en sí, podrías crear una lista y cada línea sería un diccionario en la lista o podrías hacer que `val1` sea la llave de cada elemento del diccionario

Comment: Se que es un ejercicio y lo que voy a decir no aplica a este caso, pero hay que tener en cuenta que en un escenario real en un csv (pues el txt se parece mucho a uno) no es buena idea usar split, ya que entonces si una frase esta entre comillas y tiene punto y coma, la frase sera separada en cada punto y coma. La mejor opcion es usar algo pensado para leer csvs, como el modulo csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se puede interpretar de dos maneras:

**Diccionario de listas**

Creas un diccionario donde cada entrada es una lista de los valores a través de todas las personas.

En este código se implementa inicializando el diccionario con listas vacias y agregando los datos de una persona en cada iteración:

```
d = {}
d["id"] = []
d["nombre"] = []
d["apellido"] = []
d["nacimiento"] = []

with open("personas.txt") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        (val1, val2, val3, val4) = linea.split(";")
        d["id"].append(val1)
        d["nombre"].append(val2)
        d["apellido"].append(val3)
        d["nacimiento"].append(val4)

print(d)
```

produce:

```
{'id': ['1', '2', '3', '4'], 'nombre': ['Carlos', 'Manuel', 'Rosa', 'David'], 'apellido': ['Pérez', 'Heredia', 'Campos', 'García'], 'nacimiento': ['05/01/1989\n', '26/12/1973\n', '12/06/1961\n', '25/07/2006']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Lista de diccionarios**

Una lista donde cada elemento es un diccionario correspondiente a una persona en particular.

En este caso partimos con una lista vacía y en cada iteración creamos un diccionario, agregandolo a la lista.

```
lista = []

with open("personas.txt") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        (val1, val2, val3, val4) = linea.split(";")
        d = {}
        d["id"] = val1
        d["nombre"] = val2
        d["apellido"] = val3
        d["nacimiento"] = val4
        lista.append(d)

print(lista)
```

produce:

```
[{'id': '1', 'nombre': 'Carlos', 'apellido': 'Pérez', 'nacimiento': '05/01/1989\n'}, {'id': '2', 'nombre': 'Manuel', 'apellido': 'Heredia', 'nacimiento': '26/12/1973\n'}, {'id': '3', 'nombre': 'Rosa', 'apellido': 'Campos', 'nacimiento': '12/06/1961\n'}, {'id': '4', 'nombre': 'David', 'apellido': 'García', 'nacimiento': '25/07/2006'}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```